# When to update a record - during a query iteration or afterwards?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I've read that returning an entire table as an object takes longer than simply returning the fields needed. However, I currently run a query that returns a table object plus a couple of other fields from other tables. I do this because when I iterate through the query result I can update the table object as I go based upon the query results. My understanding is that if I simply returned the fields I wanted then this would come back as a named tuple where I can't edit the attributes. This means I would have to iterate through the query result and then re-query the database using an `id` field to update records one by one.

By way of a simplified example for my current method:

```
matches = dal.session.query(Table1, Table2.date))
matches = matches.join(Table2, Table2.id_.__eq__(Table1.table1_id))
for m in matches:
    if m.date > m.Table1.date:
        m.Table1.more_recent_date = 1
dal.session.commit()
```

An alternative that doesn't return a table object would be this:

```
matches = dal.session.query(Table1.id_, Table2.date))
matches = matches.join(Table2, Table2.id_.__eq__(Table1.table1_id))
for m in matches:
    table1 = dal.session.query(Table1).filter(Table1.id_.__eq__(m.id_))
    if m.date > table1.date:
        table1.more_recent_date = 1
dal.session.commit()
```

I'm trying to get my head around which of these is the best approach. By best I really mean fastest as there are millions of records in `Table1` (100+ fields too) and tens of thousands in `Table2`. Unless of course there are other important considerations I'm not aware of. I could time the two methods but I thought I'd ask a question here first. You guys are usually good at telling me both ways are rubbish and there's a much better third way :-)

I should mention that the reason I'm updating adding new records based on existing records is that eventually there will be 35-40 new records of varying types - some of which take a long time to calculate (the date example above is just a simple example). To save time in the future I'd like to 'engineer' these records and store them rather than creating them from queries each time.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you note, measuring is the only way to be sure.

In general, your biggest time cost is likely to be the number of round-trips to the database; the number of columns in each query will likely be a much smaller effect, if it's noticeable at all.

Depending on what you're doing with it later, it's also a question whether you want to store the `more_recent_date` information in the database; if it's a temporary variable, you may be able to store it in memory instead (as a list of `table1` objects or set of `table1.id` numbers), or immediately use it for calculation (eg keep a running total rather than marking the records then summing them).

Comment: Thanks for replying. So your hunch is probably option 1 is likely to be the fastest? On the storing front; they're permanent variables sadly but thanks for the tip!

Comment: Yeah, option 1 sounds faster. If it's still not fast enough, you could accumulate the updates in memory and do them all at once (or in batches) using bulk operations.